# Why is this connection read-only?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, greendao

I'm using greenDao as ORM, now I'm trying to make the app multi-threading because the performance issues.
Here is how I'm opening the connection:

```
class appClass extends Application{
@Override    
public void onCreate(){
     DaoMaster.OpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.OpenHelper(this, "my-db", null);
     final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
     final DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
     daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
}
```

sometimes the app crash with this

> .SQLiteException: Cannot execute this statement because it might
>   modify the database but the connection is read-only.

Here the Stacktrace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.my.app.android/com.my.app.android.ui.ListActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Cannot execute this statement
>   because it might modify the database but the connection is read-only.
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3581)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1638)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Cannot execute
>   this statement because it might modify the database but the connection
>   is read-only.
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.throwIfStatementForbidden(SQLiteConnection.java:1026)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:730)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1754)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1682)
>       at com.my.app.android.orm.generated.ObjektDao.deleteOPTempTable(ObjektDao.java:479)
>       at com.my.app.android.orm.generated.ObjektDao.reBuildOPTempTable(ObjektDao.java:544)
>       at com.my.app.android.TempTablesUtils.checkTempTables(TempTablesUtils.java:132)
>       at com.my.app.android.ui.ListActivity.onRestart(ListActivity.java:94)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestart(Instrumentation.java:1344)
>       at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:7088)
>       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7099)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
>       ... 8 more

Why is the connection read-only in this case ?

Comment: You should post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you already have connections that perhaps haven't been closed.

More specifically the message is issued from within **[SQLiteConnection.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/e5360fb/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConnection.java)** lines 709-714 are:-

```
private void throwIfStatementForbidden(PreparedStatement statement) {
    if (mOnlyAllowReadOnlyOperations && !statement.mReadOnly) {
        throw new SQLiteException("Cannot execute this statement because it "
                + "might modify the database but the connection is read-only.");
    }
}
```

The comments in the file include :-

> /**  * Represents a SQLite database connection.  * Each connection
>   wraps an instance of a native `sqlite3` object.  *
>
> *
>   When database connection pooling is enabled, there can be multiple
>   active  * connections to the same database.  Otherwise there is
>   typically only one  * connection per database.  *
>
> * When the
>   SQLite WAL feature is enabled, multiple readers and one writer  * can
>   concurrently access the database.  Without WAL, readers and writers  *
>   are mutually exclusive.  *
>
> *  *
>
> ### Ownership and concurrency
>   guarantees
>
> *
>
> * Connection objects are not thread-safe. 
>   They are acquired as needed to  * perform a database operation and are
>   then returned to the pool.  At any  * given time, a connection is
>   either owned and used by a {@link SQLiteSession}  * object or the
>   {@link SQLiteConnectionPool}.  Those classes are  * responsible for
>   serializing operations to guard against concurrent  * use of a
>   connection.  *
>
> * The guarantee of having a single owner
>   allows this class to be implemented  * without locks and greatly
>   simplifies resource management.  *
>
> *  *
>
> ### Encapsulation
>   guarantees
>
> *
>
> * The connection object object owns *all* of
>   the SQLite related native  * objects that are associated with the
>   connection.  What's more, there are  * no other objects in the system
>   that are capable of obtaining handles to  * those native objects. 
>   Consequently, when the connection is closed, we do  * not have to
>   worry about what other components might have references to  * its
>   associated SQLite state -- there are none.  *
>
> * Encapsulation
>   is what ensures that the connection object's  * lifecycle does not
>   become a tortured mess of finalizers and reference  * queues.  *
>
> *  * @hide  */

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
So if any thread try to execute a query, I need to check first if the db status is open or close ? and close the connection after each query ? 
What if the connection is open when is needed by another thread?
What is you suggestion ?
Thanks

Comment: I've never used multiple threads, rather I just searched on the message and found the above. This article may be of use though [Transactions and threads in SQLite on Android](https://medium.com/inloop/transactions-and-threads-in-sqlite-on-android-215e46670f2d), at the bottom there is a section titled *Avoiding most DB multi-thread related issues*, which perhaps suggests using content providers. I've also never used greenDAO which may well complicate matters.